# If I have two consecutive J-1 visas that overlap, would I need to leave the US and come back?

Tags: visas, usa, j1-visas

I have two internships in the US that are 16 weeks each. The first one is from early May to the last week of August. The second one is from the first week of September to late December. There is a period of five business days (plus four days in the weekend) between the two internships.

As someone who is not a citizen of the US, I'll be obtaining J-1 visas. It appears I can't combine the two visas into one 8-month long visa since the two companies and J-1 visa sponsors are different. As a result, I'd need two separate visas.

Would I be required to leave the country and enter again to get the new visa? How would the process work? It is very likely my first visa's expiry date would overlap with my second internship, so would I be allowed to stay in the US since I'd always have a valid visa (although it would switch in between the two internships)?

Comment: I don't think you can get two visas like that. If you cannot arrange with these two employers to make one application, I suspect you would need to leave the US in between. You can (depending on conditions) stay for a month after the end of the work period, which would cover your five days, but that seems irrelevant as you would need one J-1 for the whole period (I believe).

Comment: You enter with one and then extend status when the first one ends to cover the second. Change of status unfortunately takes months so by the time it gets approved you would probably have finished the second one. Also, you could use the $370 fee to fly a short cheap trip to say Dominican Republic or Jamaica instead and apply for the new visa there in two days. Your choice.